# Linking Library documents in a List

Tags: sharepoint

The scenario:
Pdf-documents are stored in a Library.
A List has links(urls) to the documents in the Library.

Wanted solution:
1. When clicking the link the document should be opened in the pdf-client application (Adobe/Nitro).
2. Then the user makes comments in the pdf.
3. By clicking Save-Icon in the pdf-client application, the document is updated in the Library.

In other words, I want the link in the List to act like I am directly accessing the Library document in the Library.

Is this possible?

Regards,
Rune

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

It's unclear how you created the link list. If you create a document library, however, there's the option to add a link content type to the document library. This enables the user to create documents of type link, providing a URL and a description. Under the hood, these link items are server-side redirect to whatever the URL points to. Just as if you typed in the URL directly in the browser.

Whether the PDF can be saved back to SharePoint depends on the program used. It needs to be SharePoint-aware. That's how the Office applications accomplish the task.